# Wordpress how to perform nested/multilevel querys for custom post types

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm trying to show lists of different custom post types (named "leistungen") with corresponding submodules.

So under the URL "/services" I want something like this.

**Service A**

- Module A1
- Module A2
- Module A3

**Service B**

- Module B1
- Module B2
- Module B3

I have the following setup in the UI

[image]

My current archive loop looks like this. I seem to miss a thing, but I don't get it after hours of trying.

```
  <?php
  $outer_args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'leistungen',
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_parent'   => 0
  );

  $outer_query = new WP_Query($args);

  if ($outer_query->have_posts()) : ?>

    <?php while ($outer_query->have_posts()) : $outer_query->the_post(); ?>

      <?php $outer_id = get_the_ID(); ?>
      <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

      <?php $issue = new WP_Query(array(
        'numberposts'   => -1,
        'post_type'  => 'leistungen',
        'post_parent'  => $outer_id,
      )); ?>

      <?php
      if ($inner_query->have_posts()) ?>
      <?php while ($inner_query->have_posts()) : $inner_query->the_post(); ?>
        <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
      <?php $inner_query->reset_postdata(); ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

**Currently, i neither get results nor any errors.**

Comment: I neither get results nor errors.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `WP_Query` with combination of `get_pages` to achieve what you want.

```php
$args = array(
  'post_type'      => 'leistungen',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
);

$results = new WP_Query($args);

if ($results) {
  while ($results->have_posts()) {
    $results->the_post();

    echo "<h3>" . get_the_title() . "<h3>";

    $sub_pages_args = array(
      'post_type' => 'leistungen',
      'child_of'  => get_the_ID(),
    );

    $sub_pages = get_pages($sub_pages_args);

    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($sub_pages as $sub_page) {
      echo "<li>";
      echo $sub_page->post_title;
      echo "</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
  }
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Which outputs this:

```
Service A

    Module A1
    Module A2
    Module A3

Service B

    Module B1
    Module B2
    Module B3
```

Tested and works! Let me know if you could get it to work too!

Answer (score 0):

I had a couple of smaller typos in my code that  I just overlooked a couple of times:

- Misspelled variable
- missing colon
- missing closing endif